# Can you get viruses on iPhone from downloaded app?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, malware

I downloaded an app for downloading things from the internet, mainly gaming videos off of YouTube. At first everything was working fine, but I got this generic you've won popup and accidentally pressed the only option on the screen (you've won) is it possible for that app to infect my phone with malware from that popup?

Comment: Probably not! What was the app exactly (provide a link to it or the full name, if you can)?

Comment: It was just called Downloader, but that's all I remember

Comment: If you're talking about [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downloader/id835382053?mt=8) it doesn't look too sketchy! Remember that Apple reviews the code of every single app before it gets on the App Store.

Comment: It was more similar to this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browser-file-manager-for-documents/id979401801?mt=8, but alright, cool, hopefully my phone doesn't die

Comment: that app looks pretty safe in and of itself, but of course it's *possible* for it to download a file that exploits a vulnerability in your phone. That said, if you're phone is un-jailbroken and up-to-date software-wise, you'll probably be safe. You can try as hard as you want to infect your iPhone with some malware and it *probably* won't work :).

Comment: Alright, coolio bro